# Installing using dpkg -i

Tags: dpkg

I was trying to install some aplications after downloading the file x.deb and after doing:

```
sudo dpkg -i x.deb
```

The result is always:

```
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
```

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 1):

`dpkg` tells you it's doing something with the `.desktop` files, menu definitions, icons, ... from the package.